# How to reset my weekly loan calculation to 0 and take another loan weekly loan payment?

Tags: javascript, html

Right now i am working on a loan page and it is almost finished. Can someone tell me how to reset my repay form when i make a new loan if my current loan have been fully paid. I created  function. The first one is to calculate the loan amount, weekly loan amount and weekly period amount to pay the loan.

Here is the HTML page:

```html
<div id="loanpage">
  <form id="loanform">
    <h3>Loan Calculator</h3>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Loan amount required</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" min="100" max="100,000" id="loanamount" autocomplete="off" required placeholder="Max 100,000" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>currency</td>
        <td>
          <select name="currency" value="currency" id="currency">
            <option id="currency1"></option>
            <option id="currency2"></option>
            <option id="currency3"></option>
            <option id="currency4"></option>
            <option id="currency5"></option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Repayment period in years</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" min="1" max="5" id="period" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Max 5 years" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Interest p.a. </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value="5%" disabled id="interest" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" value="Calculate weekly instalment" class="btn btn-success" onclick="loanForm();" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Total amount payable</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" disabled id="payableloan" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Weekly instalment amount</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" disabled id="weeklyloan" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Number of instalments</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" disabled id="numberInstalment" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <div id="repayform">
    <h3>Loan payment</h3>
    <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Total amount payable</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="repayamount" disabled autocomplete="off" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Total instalments paid</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="paidloan" disabled id="amountPaid" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Loan balance payable</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" disabled name="paidloan" id="currentBalance" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Instalment amount due</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" disabled name="paidloan" id="due" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="paybtn" onclick="payNow()" value="Pay now" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript file:

```js
let loanInterestRate = 5;
let principal = document.getElementById("loanamount").value;
let userCurrency = document.getElementById("currency").value;
let loanPeriod = document.getElementById("period").value;
let interestTotal = (loanInterestRate / 100) * loanPeriod + 1;
let loanAmountPayable = principal * interestTotal;
let loanPeriodInWeeks = loanPeriod * 52;
let weeklyInstalment = loanAmountPayable / loanPeriodInWeeks;
let instalmentPaidTotal = 0;
let payButton = document.getElementById("paybtn");

function loanForm() {
  principal = document.getElementById("loanamount").value;
  userCurrency = document.getElementById("currency").value;
  loanPeriod = document.getElementById("period").value;
  interestTotal = (loanInterestRate / 100) * loanPeriod + 1;
  loanAmountPayable = principal * interestTotal;
  loanPeriodInWeeks = loanPeriod * 52;
  weeklyInstalment = loanAmountPayable / loanPeriodInWeeks;
  document.getElementById("payableloan").value = userCurrency + " " + loanAmountPayable.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("weeklyloan").value = userCurrency + " " + weeklyInstalment.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("numberInstalment").value = loanPeriodInWeeks + " weeks";
  document.getElementById("repayamount").value = userCurrency + " " + loanAmountPayable.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("due").value = userCurrency + " " + weeklyInstalment.toFixed(2);
}

function payNow() {
  instalmentPaidTotal = weeklyInstalment + instalmentPaidTotal;
  let loanBalancePayable = loanAmountPayable - instalmentPaidTotal;
  if (loanBalancePayable > 0) {
    document.getElementById("amountPaid").value =
      userCurrency + " " + instalmentPaidTotal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("currentBalance").value =
      userCurrency + " " + loanBalancePayable.toFixed(2);
  } else {
    alert("You loan account is 0");
  }
}
```

Any help and suggestion is appreciated and welcomed.

Comment: I have formatted your code to look better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looks of it, you can do two things to reset.

1. JavaScript Variables Reset
2. HTML Form Reset

Both the above can be done using JavaScript. What you need to do is:

```js
// Since a few things are dependent on the form values, first reset the form.
document.getElementById("loanform").reset();
// JavaScript Variables Reset.
// Reset to the initialisation data.
loanInterestRate = 5;
principal = document.getElementById("loanamount").value;
userCurrency = document.getElementById("currency").value;
loanPeriod = document.getElementById("period").value;
interestTotal = (loanInterestRate / 100) * loanPeriod + 1;
loanAmountPayable = principal * interestTotal;
loanPeriodInWeeks = loanPeriod * 52;
weeklyInstalment = loanAmountPayable / loanPeriodInWeeks;
instalmentPaidTotal = 0;
```

The above should work. Let me know if there's any question.

A best way is to have the above in a function:

```js
function init() {
  // Since a few things are dependent on the form values, first reset the form.
  document.getElementById("loanform").reset();
  // JavaScript Variables Reset.
  // Reset to the initialisation data.
  loanInterestRate = 5;
  principal = document.getElementById("loanamount").value;
  userCurrency = document.getElementById("currency").value;
  loanPeriod = document.getElementById("period").value;
  interestTotal = (loanInterestRate / 100) * loanPeriod + 1;
  loanAmountPayable = principal * interestTotal;
  loanPeriodInWeeks = loanPeriod * 52;
  weeklyInstalment = loanAmountPayable / loanPeriodInWeeks;
  instalmentPaidTotal = 0;
}
// Call the function...
init();
```

You may name the above function as `init()` or `reset()` as per your convenience.

Comment: Thank You Praveen. It works. i really appreciate it